# Takes 2 clicks of Enter to get a response into the recyclerview

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am making an app for one of my classes, a project that we got to choose for ourselves. Right now it's mostly working except for a few things here and there. One of those things is that it takes 2 or 3 clicks of enter to get the app to redo the recyclerview with the updated information.

```
public View.OnKeyListener search = new View.OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        searchItem = "";//clears it out before the use of it

        if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))//only executes when the ENTER key is hit
        {
            if(searchItem != searchBar.getText().toString())//as long as the bar isn't empty
            {
                searchItem = searchBar.getText().toString();//grabs the search term and puts it in the variable

            }

            // hide the virtual keyboard
            ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

            //clear out the recyclerview
            clearRecycler();

            //API Call one
            goGetSearch(searchItem, searchType);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Here is the clearRecycler method that I call. I removed items using for loops because the .clear wasn't working correctly for me for some reason.

```
public void clearRecycler()
    {
        int size = details.size();
        if (size > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                details.remove(0);//arraylist
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < OnlyIds.size(); i++)
            {
                OnlyIds.remove(0);//arraylist
            }
            myAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
        }
    }
```

If there is any other code that you would need to help me fix this problem let me know, I think everything should be here.

Answer (score 0):

**You are not comparing the Strings correctly**

**You shouldn't use `==` you must use `.equals()`:**

```
.........

if(!searchBar.getText().toString().equals(searchItem))//as long as the bar isn't empty
{
searchItem = searchBar.getText().toString();//grabs the search term and puts it in the variable
}
.........
.........
```

Comment: That still gives the same result. I need to hit the enter key 2 times still after changing that